# What does a CSS `font-size` property defined as a percentage mean?

Tags: css

Using the CSS `font-size` property, one can specify the size as a percentage. What does this percentage refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The percentage refers to the size percentage of the elements parent.  I think the default browser font size is 14px, so:

```
  p{ font-size: 100%; } /* 14px */
  p{ font-size: 85%; } /* 12px */
```

It starts to get a little more complicated if you have this:

```
   <style type="text/css">
        div{ font-size: 20px; }
        p{ font-size: 80%; } /* 16px */
   </style>

   <div>
       <p>Some Test</p>
   </div>
```

Since I set a pixel size for the parent div, and a percentage size for the child paragraph, the child paragraph uses the parent pixel size as the base measurement.

Comment: "The default text size in browsers is 16px." -http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp